# Glitch Issue When I Move the Camera

Tags: android, arcore, anchorpoint

I am working with Android AR Core App For Rendering the Object in the Plane but the Issue occur **when i move the camera,the object hit point(Anchor Position) location** was changed.

Github Link : https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's by design. The anchor's position will be updated as ARCore's understanding of the world improves (https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Anchor). So I think that glitches can happen.